# How can i create splash screen not using thread or something like that in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, gif, splash-screen

I want to introduce my logo in 5 seconds at start. But it must be motional. I used thread my logo was stoped in 5 seconds. I thought that maybe I could use "gif" but it can not work. I want to show my logo motional. How can i do it in Android?

Comment: Why do you not want a separate thread? This allows your splash screen to show while the rest of the program loads which seems like the right idea to me. If its stopping your animation its probably an error not the use of a thread itself

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to show a splash screen for 5 seconds and then go on, simply use a handler in your Activity's onCreate and post a delayed runnable at 5000 milliseconds. Inside the runnable, simply start a new activity and remove the handler's callbacks. If you mean you want to fade some image in, then you'll need an alpha animation.

Comment: I mean that like this video's first 5 seconds http://youtu.be/c1EG9n7OXSw // It does not stop , if ı used to thread splash screen ıt would wait 5 seconds as a stop. In short how do i make the the first 6 seconds like this video. @LuxuryMode